# Eigenvalues broken in Version 12.0

Tags: bugs, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

**Bug introduced in 12.0 and fixed in 12.1**

---

The following code calculates the eigenvalues of a certain complex matrix, which come in pairs of opposite complex numbers. Therefore one can check whether the sum of all eigenvalues is equal to the trace of the matrix, which is zero.

This is indeed the case in Version 10.1 & 11.3 as far as I tested. However, Version 12.0 (Windows, Mac, Linux) gives something seriously wrong.

```
NN = 374; R = 0.05;
t1 = -1 + Cos[x] - I Sin[x] + I R; t1p = -1 + Cos[x] + I Sin[x] + 
  I R;
mat[x_] = 
  DiagonalMatrix[Table[If[EvenQ[n], t1, -1], {n, 0, 2 NN - 1 - 1}], 
    1] + DiagonalMatrix[
    Table[If[EvenQ[n], t1p, -1], {n, 0, 2 NN - 1 - 1}], -1] + 
   DiagonalMatrix[Table[If[EvenQ[n], -1, 0], {n, 0, 2 NN - 1 - 3}], 
    3] + DiagonalMatrix[
    Table[If[EvenQ[n], -1, 0], {n, 0, 2 NN - 1 - 3}], -3];
mat0 = mat[-0.2 \[Pi]];
Tr@mat0  (* 0. *)
Total@Eigenvalues@mat0  (* 0.394003 - 0.566499 I *)
```

I would rather switch back to 11.3 for a while. This looks really dangerous...

---

**Original post of a more complex matrix with the same issue**:

The code plots the real part of adding each pair. So the correct plot should be just zeros everywhere. This is the case in Version 10.1 & 11.3 as far as I tested (scattered numbers around $10^{-14}$ or so). However, Version 12.0 (Windows, Mac, Linux) gives something different as shown below.

```
NN = 200; R = 0.05;
xlist = Table[x, {x, -0.2 \[Pi], 0.2 \[Pi], 0.01}];
modl[n_] := 2*^-3 (Quotient[n, 2] - NN/2);
t1 = -1 + Cos[x] - I Sin[x] + I R; t1p = -1 + Cos[x] + I Sin[x] + I R;
t2a[n_] := -1 - modl[n]; t2b[n_] := -1 + modl[n];
mat[x_] = 
  DiagonalMatrix[
    Table[If[EvenQ[n], t1, t2a[n]], {n, 0, 2 NN - 1 - 1}], 1] + 
   DiagonalMatrix[
    Table[If[EvenQ[n], t1p, t2a[n]], {n, 0, 2 NN - 1 - 1}], -1] + 
   DiagonalMatrix[
    Table[If[EvenQ[n], t2b[n], 0], {n, 0, 2 NN - 1 - 3}], 3] + 
   DiagonalMatrix[
    Table[If[EvenQ[n], t2b[n], 0], {n, 0, 2 NN - 1 - 3}], -3];
list0 = Sort@Re@Eigenvalues[mat[xlist[[3]]]];
list0p = Table[list0[[i]] + list0[[2 NN - i + 1]], {i, NN}];
ListPlot[Tooltip@list0p, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: You should redo your calculation in a fresh kernel; your code produces a scatterplot of points with near-zero y coordinates in my case (around $10^{-14}$) in both versions 11.3 and 12.0.

Comment: [tag:bugs]: "*This tag is reserved for questions where the problem has been vetted by this community and the observed behavior is confirmed to be a bug. Please do not use this tag for new questions.*"

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: @ulvi I even restarted the computer.

Comment: A simpler test is comparing `Tr[matrix]` with `Total[Eigenvalues[matrix]]` which shows a large discrepancy. I think this is worth reporting to support. It happens on OSX as well.

Comment: @Carl Woll. Interesting: On my machine (Windows 10; version 12.0) `Tr[matrix]` gives 0. and `Total[Eigenvalues[matrix]]` gives `-2.23821*10^-13 - 2.66454*10^-15 I`.

Comment: @CarlWoll no time to test before I post this questio—(clarification?) suggestion? Someone should try to see if this carries to Eigensystem, maybe some core piece that relates these two is broken? Otherwise we could get around it (for now) with just grabbing the first portion of Eigensystem[] output

Comment: @ulvi what versions did you have previously? Uninstalled them to install the newest version? I’ll respond with testing results in the morning. Hope someone has found the answer by then!

Comment: I see this problem in V12 on Linux

Comment: Eigensystem is broken too.

Comment: @ulvi what day did you download the new version?

Comment: Filing a report (apparently that has not been done to date).

Comment: My `$Version` gives `12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019)`

Comment: I'm under MMA12 under Windows and I got `-0.551716242833052 - 0.263815420085667 I` for `Total[Eigenvalues[mat0]]` and I also got a different picture from the above, though it is wrong too

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Any update following the bug report?

Comment: To assist with debugging: is the result of `Tr[Last[SchurDecomposition[mat0, RealBlockDiagonalForm -> False]]]` the same as the result of `Tr[mat0]`, or with `Total[Eigenvalues[mat0]]`?

Comment: @xiaohuamao To my understanding, the problem is with the MKL library. It has been fixed in the development version (which uses a newer version of MKL).

Comment: @ilian by development you mean prerelease?

Comment: Not in general, but this issue is also fixed in the 12.1 prerelease builds

Comment: @ilian Is there any estimated release date of the newer version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixed in 12.1

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

```
ClearAll[x, n];
NN = 374; R = 0.05;
t1 = -1 + Cos[x] - I Sin[x] + I R; t1p = -1 + Cos[x] + I Sin[x] + I R;
mat[x_] = 
  DiagonalMatrix[Table[If[EvenQ[n], t1, -1], {n, 0, 2 NN - 1 - 1}], 
    1] + DiagonalMatrix[
    Table[If[EvenQ[n], t1p, -1], {n, 0, 2 NN - 1 - 1}], -1] + 
   DiagonalMatrix[Table[If[EvenQ[n], -1, 0], {n, 0, 2 NN - 1 - 3}], 
    3] + DiagonalMatrix[
    Table[If[EvenQ[n], -1, 0], {n, 0, 2 NN - 1 - 3}], -3];
mat0 = mat[-0.2 \[Pi]];
Tr@mat0  (*0.*)
(Total@Eigenvalues@mat0) // Chop
```

Comment: Please edit and update the bug header too.

Answer (score 32):

Not a solution but too big for a comment. There seems to be a catastrophic failure in `Eigenvalues` happening that is not due to the matrix being crazy. As a diagnostic, let's calculate the smallest (by absolute value) eigenvalue of the upper-left $n\times n$ part of the matrix

```
M = mat[xlist[[3]]];
```

For odd $n$ the answer is zero, so let's only do this for even $n$. We do this in two ways

1. Calculate all eigenvalues and pick the one with the smallest absolute value:

```
    e1[n_?EvenQ] := M[[;; n, ;; n]] // Eigenvalues // Abs // Min
```

2. Calculate only the smallest eigenvalue (by absolute value) with the [Arnoldi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi_iteration):

```
    e2[n_?EvenQ] := Eigenvalues[M[[;; n, ;; n]], 1, 
      Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "Magnitude", "Shift" -> 0}] // First // Abs
```

Method (2) is very reliable, whereas method (1) breaks down for $n=358$ and above:

[image]

Considering that the Arnoldi algorithm has no problems with this matrix, there seems to be something really strange going on in method 1.

```
$Version
(* 12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019) *)
```

Comment: This persists for Eigensystem also.

Answer (score 12):

**Edit: Eigensystem fixed in 12.1 in addition to Eigenvalues**

I attempted a workaround, to see if `Eigensystem` had any issues also. It does. This is very unfortunate.

(Will we have to wait for 12.1 for the fix (?!))
**(We waited for 12.1 for the fix (!!))**

My code here:

```
e3[n_?EvenQ] := Eigensystem[M[[;; n, ;; n]]][[1]] // Abs // Min
```

Produces the following, which matches with @Roman shows:

[image: Issue persisting for Eigensystem]

(Apologies the colors/styles don't match with the plot from @Roman !!)

```
$Version
(* 12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019) *)
```

Comment: The generated eigenvectors aren't even really eigenvectors of the matrix, so the error is not just in the eigenvalues.

Comment: If I understand what you mean, this would be some fundamental (internal) issue with the eigensolver being used? Maybe some error in the linear decomposition being used?

Comment: Yes it looks like a serious foul in the default "Direct" diagonalizer. This is very surprising for something that's been around for such a long time (coded in LAPACK).

Comment: @Roman Perhaps we should have a chat room to discuss this, but the last stable release of LAPACK was in September of 2017? So either there is some issue with the implementation within this version of mma or we have the same issues as we downloaded 12.0 on adjacent days, very near release.

Comment: Let's let WR debug this one for themselves. Maybe they aren't using LAPACK.

Comment: @Roman very true. The issue exists on “Wolfram Cloud” also, which, apparently is now not Mathematica Online....so maybe there is some other issue occurring? My concern/want to fix this is that this method is a primary part of my current research, and I do not entirely understand how to, in a generalized way, replace the Arnoldi method. I enjoyed that Eigensystem produces orthogonalized vectors and values.....I don’t know how to ask a question on this, as I cannot do the necessary research, but I fear my datasets are wrong now.

Comment: No need to fear, there are easy sanity checks, as @CarlWoll has already posted one (trace rule). A sanity check for the eigenvectors is to compute `{eval, evec} = Eigensystem[M]` and then go `evec.Transpose[M].Inverse[evec] - DiagonalMatrix[eval] // Norm` which should give zero (or something close to it) if the eigenvectors `evec` truly diagonalize the matrix `M`.

Comment: @Roman perfect! Thank you :) you rock! My matrix methods skills on the other hand....need work! I’ll be checking ~30000 of them this evening, I’ll report back with success or fail. Here’s to hoping sizes of ~100x100 or 200x200 go relatively unaffected!

Comment: Ill see about posting more code to the answer here in the morning, but I wanted to notify you all that for at least a numeric & very well defined functional matrix (meaning I had a 50x50 matrix that was programmatically defined) I get consistent `EigInSanityChecks` of ~.000008 give or take a zero (don’t hurt me! Hah!) But even this is troubling, although likely just a numerical error in this case, and not contributions from the eigensolver discrepancies.

Comment: This sort of breakage of previously working code now happens so frequently on major updates that I've decided to keep one or more old executables of Mathematica on hand. Note: test suites should be catching all of these!

Answer (score 4):

I am not qualified to be at this site because the last time I used eigenvectors was well over half a century ago.  The word "stiff matrix" came back to me, so I increased the precision of the author's code by rounding the two real numbers to 50 places.  It took forever to compute, but Mathematica solved the problem accurately.  That is, R = N[5/100, 50]; and mat0 = mat[N[-2/10 [Pi], 50]];  I ended up with zero to 47 places.

Occasionally--when solving differential equations numerically--I came across stiff systems, so I checked for this condition prior to working with them (I forget the method I used).

Again, sorry for my layman's interjection.

Nick Bagley

Comment: Charles, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#Condition_number), "[...] the eigenvalue problem for all normal matrices is well-conditioned." So stiffness should not play a role here, unless a bad algorithm is being used.