# Solution to the inverted pendulum problem (system of non-linear ODE)

Tags: differential-equations, control-systems

A classic control systems problem is that of the translational inverted pendulum, as shown below. By applying a force $f(t)$ to the car (e.g. through a DC motor attached to the car), the goal is to adequately adjust $x(t)$ and $\theta(t)$ such that the rod is mostly vertical (i.e. $\theta = 0$). Let $M_p$ be the mass of the pendulum (actually, the ball), $M_c$ the mass of the car, $L$ the length of the rod, and $g$ the magnitude of the acceleration of gravity.

[image: Diagram of the translational inverted pendulum, with positive direction for the variables]

After some assumptions (i.e. massless rod, zero moment of inertia for the ball, no friction between wheels of the car and the ground), but without any approximations, [the system of two second-order non-linear ODEs](https://youtu.be/5qJY-ZaKSic) is

$\cos{[\theta(t)]} \ddot x(t) - L \ddot \theta(t) + g \sin{[\theta(t)]} = 0 \tag*{}$

$-M_p L \cos{[\theta(t)]} \ddot \theta(t) + M_p L \sin{[\theta(t)]} \dot \theta^2(t) + (M_c + M_p) \ddot x(t) = f(t) \tag*{}$

Using Mathematica, I'd like to get the particular solution for this problem, given the initial conditions   $\theta(0) = \theta_0$, $\dot \theta(0) = \theta_1$, $x(0) = x_0$ and $\dot x(0) = x_1$. Now, I don't need a symbolic solution; we can assume all initials conditions to be zero except $\theta(0) = \pi/10$, and letting $M_p = 0.1$ (in kg), $M_c = 10$, $L = 0.03$ (in meters), $g = 9.81$ (in meters per second squared), and $f(t) = 0$. In such case, after defining the variables, this is my code for the ODEs:

```
DSolve[{Cos[θ[t]] x''[t] - L θ''[t] + g Sin[θ[t]] == 0, -Mp L Cos[θ[t]] θ''[t] + Mp L Sin[θ[t]] (θ'[t])^2 + (Mc + Mp) x''[t] == 0 , θ[0] == θ0, θ'[0] == θ1, x[0] == x0, x'[0] == x1}, {θ[t], x[t]}, t]
```

However, Mathematica outputs just what I typed, without solving:

[image: Screenshot of result in Mathematica]

I only want the expression of the unknown functions $\theta(t)$ and $x(t)$. Do I have to use NDSolve? If so, how? I know this system is unstable but is controllable and observable.

Comment: Most of the nonlinear ODEs don't have symbolic solutions. Have you read this?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/206565/1871

Comment: @xzczd Yes. That system is already stabilized, mine isn't. And I don't want to animate the solution yet, only get the expressions for $x(t)$ and $\theta(t)$, and then plot those two against time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do I have to use NDSolve?

Yes

> If so, how?

Something like

```
ClearAll[θ,t,g,x];
L   =  1;
Mp  =  2;
Mc  =  3;
θ0  = 5 Degree;
x1  = 0;
x0  = 4;
θ1  = 0;
g   = 9.81;

ode1 = Cos[θ[t]] x''[t] - L θ''[t] + g Sin[θ[t]] == 0;
ode2 = - Mp L Cos[θ[t]] θ''[t] + Mp L Sin[θ[t]] (θ'[t])^2 + (Mc + Mp) x''[t] == 0;
ic  = {θ[0] == θ0, θ'[0] == θ1, x[0] == x0, x'[0] == x1};

sol = NDSolve[{ode1,ode2,ic},{θ, x}, {t,0,5}]
```

See help on `NDSolve` on how to do processing on result, i.e. plot, etc..

Comment: Thanks! It worked out. You forgot the minus sign in the second equation.